# Google Apps Script DocumentApp (not SpreadSheet) get hyperlinks embedded in the Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

For a scripting project (using Google Apps Script) I need to get contents of a Google Document and parse through the contents. I can do this by using

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('xxx')
  var d = doc.getBody().getText()
  Logger.log(d)
```

But this gets all the contents in form of a text. In the same document I expect to have hyperlinks. I need to get these hyperlinks to perform some action.

I know this can be done in SpreadSheetApp. I also see examples to insert Hyperlink text in a Google Document. But I am unable to find a way to get embedded hyperlink URLs from the Document.

Appreciate any help or suggestions. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getLinks() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  for(var i=0;i<body.getNumChildren();i++) {
    var child=body.getChild(i);
    var attr=child.getAttributes();
    var linkUrl=attr.LINK_URL;
    if(linkUrl) {
      Logger.log('Child Index: %s linkUrl: %s text: %s',i,linkUrl,child.asText().getText());
    }
  }
}
```